# Send viewparams GeoServer using Leaflet

Tags: geoserver, pgrouting, leaflet

I need to pass my longitudes and latitudes of origin and destination for a SQL view in GeoServer to get a WMS layer with the route.
I've performed in qgis to view and is working perfectly.

This is the view in GeoServer:

[image]

This my code to add the layer on the map. I'm using Leaflet.

```
function findRoute(){  
 route = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8888/geoserver/pgrouting/wms", {
     layers: 'pgrouting',
     viewparams: [x1:paramOrigemLng;y1:paramOrigemLat;x2:paramDestino1Lng;y2:paramDestino1Lat]
    });
}
```

Can anyone give me an example of layer viewparams the key format: value with Leaflet because I'm not hitting the syntax.
I'm doing as the link: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html

Comment: maybe this helps you: http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/ol3_client.html 
it is with OpenLayers, but maybe it makes the syntax clearer

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

viewparams: 'x1:value;y1:value;x2:value;y2:value'

please write params like this it will work